# Updating a field in the User record when assigning a license

Tags: managed-package, licenses

For reporting purposes, I would like for a (custom) field within the User object to be updated upon assigning a license of a certain managed package to a user. For this reason, I'm trying to figure out which object is used to create what is a record showing the person's name in the "Manage License" list of users of an installed package. I am guessing if I can find out which object that is I could have a trigger go off whenever a record for that object is created which is for the specified package and have it update the proper User record.

I've been fishing around Workbench trying to find which object is used for that. I thought it might be one of these : UserPackageLicense or PackageLicense. But after a couple queries those don't seem to be the right object.

Does anybody know which object is used for that ? Is it not possible anyway and so I'm wasting my time ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's [UserPackageLicense](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userpackagelicense.htm), and no, you can't write a trigger on it. Best you could do is write an hourly scheduled class that checks for changes to the object and makes the associated modification to the user, or, alternatively, just build a trigger to add/remove those records when fields on the user is edited (and make it a process to use those fields).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.